# CSRF token could not be verified

Tags: php, yii

I know this has been asked already, but my question is a bit different. In my .php file, I have:

```
<?php
/* @var $this SiteController */
$this->pageTitle=Yii::app()->name;
?>

<div id="page-content">
    <h1 class="gasparregular">Welcome back, <?php echo Yii::app()->user->table->name ?>!</h1>
    <h2 style="color:white;">Current Promotion: <?php echo Yii::app()->user->table->promo ?></h2>
    <span class="help-text">To check, please enter their xxxID:</span>

    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) 
    {

        $message=
        'First Name: '.$_POST['xxxid'].'<br />
        Last Name: '.$_POST['xxxid'].'<br />
        Phone:  '.$_POST['xxxid'].'<br />
        Email:  '.$_POST['xxxid'].'<br />
        Comments: '.$_POST['xxxid'].'
        ';

        require "phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php";

        // Instantiate Class  
        $mail = new PHPMailer();  

        // Set up SMTP  
        $mail->IsSMTP();               
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;         
        $mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl"; 
        $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com"; 
        $mail->Port = 465; 
        $mail->Encoding = '7bit';

        // Authentication  
        $mail->Username   = "xxx@xxx.com";
        $mail->Password   = "dswdcssd1yfs";

        // Compose
        $mail->SetFrom("xxx@xxx.com");
        $mail->AddReplyTo("xxx@xxx.com");
        $mail->Subject = "Hello";
        $mail->MsgHTML($message);

        // Send To  
        $mail->AddAddress("ggggdssae@hotmail.com", "Recipient Name");
        $result = $mail->Send();
        $message = $result ? 'Successfully Sent!' : 'Sending Failed!';     

        unset($mail);
        $URL="google.ca"; 

        header ("Location: $URL"); 
    }
    ?>

<form name="form1" id="form1" action="" method="post">
    <fieldset>
        <input type="text" name="xxxid" placeholder="xxx ID" />
        <br />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Validate" />
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

When I enter a number and click the validate button, it sends an email. It works fine in my local environment without Yii. But when I put it on the live site where it uses Yii, I get:

> ErrThe CSRF token could not be verified.

Comment: You're not using any of the benefits of Yii. Use MVC: manage the POST response from a controller, and put the form into a view.

Answer (score 0):

Form need to handle the CSRF, many options here:

you can disable it from the controller:

```
$this->enableCsrfValidation = false;
```

Or use an ActiveForm in the view, and it will handle CSRF.

**Updated:**

There's many questions about this issue in *Stack Overflow*, but the important thing is know that **CSRF (Cross-Site Request Forgery)** is to be sure that submitted form data comes from your app.

More info: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-request.html